# copy a certain range of one sheet to a certain specifed cell in other sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

```
   Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Copy  after:=wb2.Sheets(1)
```

The above code always overwrites the previous contents but That is not what i want.
How do I copy a certain range to other sheet at a particular cell.

Example I have to copy

```
    sheet1.range("A5:B12") set of values to sheet2.range("A4")
```

I found

```
   selection.copy and activesheet.paste ' but this is not i want
```

I want a copy and destination example . I have been googling it from long time but unable to find out the documents and source. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sheet1.Range("A5:B12").Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A4")
```