# using vba excel, search and copy the entire row to another sheet one after other

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am working in an organisation, need help.(consider a sheet having 200 entries from A1:H200)
Now My boss wants: 
1) textbox 
2) commandBox

These two should be use for searching.
After this, the searched cell's entire row should be copied and get pasted at a new sheet.

Now,as many times he searches the data should start after other. 
Example: 
A1:H1 then next from A2:H2 then fom A3:H3 & so on.
Please Help

Answer (score 1):

You should find your answer on this thread.

[copy a certain range of one sheet to a certain specifed cell in other sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077653/copy-a-certain-range-of-one-sheet-to-a-certain-specifed-cell-in-other-sheet?rq=1)

`Sheet1.Range("A5:B12").Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A4")`